# How to Iterate over RDD or DataFrames efficiently?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a DataSet

```
471,Brunt,52,273
472,Nog,27,154
473,Morn,35,38
474,Keiko,34,48 
475,Ben,52,446
```

I want to iterate over it efficiently so that I can take out multiple
info at one time from it and save somewhere like name or age etc .

```
**def retrieveData(data):
array1 = []
splitData = data.split(",")
for newData in splitData:
    if newData[1] == "will":
        array1.append(newData[1])
        
return array1      
 lines = sc.textFile("/Users/adityaverma/Documents/sparkCourse/fakefriends.csv")
 lines.take()
 getNewData = lines.map(retrieveData)
 mydata = getNewData.map(lambda x : (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)
 results = mydata.collect()
 
 This results shows an error "ile "<ipython-input-96-8b7508e2339e>", line 5, in retrieveData
  IndexError: string index out of range**
```

My approach was to pass an RDD into a python function( def extract(lines):) something like
this  and then by using if and else save the values in different arrays and then assign
those arrays to RDD again in this case I don't have to use the filter on the same RDD again
and again.

how is the possible ? is there  a way to efficiently iterate over the RDD or Dataframe once
?

Comment: if you are just doing a word count, why not use dataframe's native function instead of writing a python udf which is slower

Comment: you can use a udf which returns a struct type of the fields you want and achieve it, but if it is simple count, then dataframe's native functions is the better